# Как перенаправить поток в лог файл (!) И (!) вывести на консоль в .bat файлах?

Tags: windows, потоки-данных, логирование, bat, вывод

**Моя задача:** Настроить поток вывода в лог файл и одновременно на консоль при выполнении пакетного файла (.bat). ОС: Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise / Windows 7 Enterprise

**Что я сделал:** Разобравшись с потоками и перенаправлением я создаю логи такой строкой:

```
CALL [программа] >>%LOGFILE_NAME% 2>>&1
```

**Проблема:** При таком подходе весь текст уходить в файл (что я и добивался), но не появляется в консоли. Мой шеф хочет видеть ход выполнения.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли возможность создавать логи И одновременно выводить текст выполения в консоли?
Если это сложно сделать на винде, есть ли легкое решение сделать это с помощью линукс команд в Cygwin?

Буду благодарен за любой совет или ссылочку на посторонние источники.

Comment: Есть идея выдавать после окончания содержимое лог файла в консоль, но некоторые процессы было бы желательно мониторить вживую.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file

Comment: Этот способ работает, но не всегда корректно.Иногда выводиться только часть данных. И это происхоит только после выполнения процесса одним больгим блоком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать вызов PowerShell:

```
powershell "program | Add-Content log.txt -PassThru"
```

Comment: Я уже давно не заинтересован этим вопросом, не работаю на винде, и не могу проверить на правильность, но я отмечу его галочкой, так как он единственный.

Comment: @S.G. единственный ответ - не означает правильность

Comment: @SeniorPomidor стоит тогда убрать галочку?

Comment: @S.G. это вам решать. галочка означает, что ответ помог вам с решением проблемы, как минимум.